# How can I change Locale within the app itself

Tags: android, locale, android-softkeyboard

How to change soft keyboard language within the app itself. I want to change only the soft keyboard language.

Answer (score 0):

seems this also does the trick:

```
// creating locale
Locale locale2 = new Locale(loc); 
Locale.setDefault(locale2);
Configuration config2 = new Configuration();
config2.locale = locale2;

// updating locale
mContext.getResources().updateConfiguration(config2, null);
```